# problem for change batch size in my model

Tags: out-of-memory, transformer-model, hyperparameters, pytorch-lightning, batchsize

When I train my model(my model is a transformer that its input is featured extracted from T5 model and Vit )
I have problem for set batch_size more than 2 number

```
number of image is 25000 for training.
GPU is GTX 3090(24 gpu ram).
24 core multithreading CPU.

number of total parameter =363M
seq_len=512
max-step=100000/2
iter=100000
img:torch.Size([3, 384, 500])
tokens:torch.Size([512])
```

I want to increase batch_size from 2 to 3,4,... but I can't. and I see error
for example when I set batch_size=4, I have this error
CUDA out of memoryTried to allocat....
(I attache image for error)
But when I decrease to 2 I have not this error .
What's I wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBKcH.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as stated. You are running out of GPU memory. If you want to increase batch size and you are using pytorch lightning, try to use half-precision to consume less memory. https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/precision_basic.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your guide I do this with different number of batchsize and number of precision but It still gives the same error(out of memory...).Is there a mathematical relationship between batch_size and presicion?

Comment: The relationship between them can be complicated for mix-precision training and your model architecture. I think this post is worth reading. https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-mixed-precision-training-4b246679c7c4

Comment: I cant find any way but thank you for your guide